# Can we do computing without electricity?

Tags: arithmetic-circuits, circuits

If electricity was never discovered, could we still make funcional computers to perform some level of useful tasks?

Or won't we be able to build anything comparable in terms of computer power?

Comment: Apropos: [Mechanical circuits: electronics without electricity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrkiJZKJfpY) on YouTube.

Comment: Some level? Definitely. Comparable to today? Probably not.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: yes, there are many "computers" which run without "electricity" (in the way most computers do nowadays). Read about  [Mechanical Computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_computer), and more generally about the [history of computing hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware).

**Longer answer**: At the most basic level,

- an [abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus) is a funcional computer which allows to compute, which is a useful task;
- the term computer was actually originally used to refer to [computing women at NASA](https://www.history.com/news/human-computers-women-at-nasa) (who do use electricity in their brain and nervous system, I bet you are not counting that as electricity);

This [2021 article from Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03623-y) references more example:

> Mechanical mechanisms have been used to process information for
> millennia, with famous examples ranging from the Antikythera mechanism
> of the Ancient Greeks to the analytical machines of Charles Babbage.

Hope it helps!